# Sticky Sidebar intruding into footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is, I'm sure, an insanely simple question but quite frankly I have very limited CSS knowledge.

I have various posts such as - http://reviewelephant.com/best-3d-pens/ and as you can see there is a quick navigation sidebar that is sticky.

However, once you reach the bottom of the page it will start to invade the footer and I was wondering how you go about making it stop where the footer begins?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

set the `z-index: 99999` in footer and sticky sidebar to `z-index:99998` should do the trick, provided the background of the footer is not transparent